# On smaller screens show default device calendar

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an Angular website, and I use bootstrap calendars.
But in smaller screens the calendars are not responsive so what I have to do is that in mobile devices when clicking on the button to display native device range calendar.
How do I achieve that using Angular ?

Comment: I think that you could just use the browser's implementation. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date
<input id="date" type="date">

Comment: But on the web I have to display a calendar using ng bootstrap.
Are you saying I should use `<input id="date" type="date">` ,and have an ngIf screen is smaller than X pixels, display input id=date, else, display the calendar I already have customized?

Comment: Yes, give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks, that works for normal calendars. But what I need is range calendar.